# Regex to match C integer literals

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to use egrep/grep -E to print out the lines in C source files that contain integer literals (as described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/integer-literal-in-c-cpp-prefixes-suffixes/)). The following works for the most part, except it matches floats too:

```
egrep '\b[0-9]+' *.c
```

Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you link to a description of integer literals when you are willing to settle with numbers without a decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative Lookarounds to make sure the number isn't followed by *or preceded by* a `.`:

```
\b(?<!\.)[0-9]+(?!\.)\b
```

**Edit:**

Since you want to only match the `0` of `0x` in hex literals as you mentioned in the comments, use the following pattern instead. It works exactly like your original regex except that it doesn't match float numbers.

```
\b(?<!\.)[0-9]+(?![\.\d])
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/eDPt3i/3).

### References:

- [Regular expressions: Lookahead and Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: This solves the float problem, but now hex, binary, and octal literals are not matched.

Comment: Your original regex doesn't match hex or binary. Do you expect it to match `0x23A` and `0b101`? Because that wasn't part of your question. Or are you talking about the suffixes (U, L, UL, etc.)?

Comment: Please check this: [`\b(?<!\.)[0-9]+(?![\.\d])`](https://regex101.com/r/eDPt3i/2) and let me know if this is your expected behavior.

Comment: It won't match the entirety of hex or binary literals, but it does match the first 0, which achieves my goal of printing out the *lines* that contain literals. The literals can contain any of the suffixes and prefixes in the link I included.

Edit: Also I tried your original command and it actually doesn't work in grep because negative lookarounds are not supported.

Comment: Never mind, you just have to use the -P flag. Thanks so much!

Comment: Matching the 0 of `0x` isn't matching the hex value. Anyway, the pattern in my previous comment will match exactly what your original regex matches except for floats. I'll edit the answer now and please let me know if there's anything not clear.

Comment: There is a lot of stuff that is not matched properly. https://regex101.com/r/sf53M4/1

Comment: @wp78de, When you described your problem, you said that your regex _"works for the most part, **except** it matches floats too"_. So, I gave you a solution which works _**exactly**_ like your original regex _**except**_ that it doesn't match floats. Isn't that fair?

Comment: Now if your requirements are different, you can feel free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50382719/edit) your question and explain exactly what you're trying to match (e.g., should it include the suffix in the match or the numeric part only? etc.), and I'll help you with the regex _which, FYI, will be very complicated compared to this one_.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I am not the OP. The requirements were/are unclear - as usual.

Comment: @wp78de, Oops, sorry didn't notice. I think I need a coffee :D

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to overoptimize a pattern like this and just convert each integer literal type and the possible suffixes literally into a regex with alternations:

```
(?i)(?:0x(?:[0-9a-f]+(?:'?[0-9a-f]+)*)|0b(?:[10]+(?:'?[10]+)*)|\d+(?:'?\d+)*)(?:ull|ll|ul|l|u)?
```

Only the digit separators require some more work: a separator cannot be followed by another separator and can only appear between numbers.

Suffixes are allowed for hex and binary too, as tested with C++14 [here](https://ideone.com/15nXnG).

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/YmMUSY/2/)

Note: The pattern is designed to be case-insensitive.

Run it like this: `egrep -ei "(?:0x(?:[0-9a-f]+(?:'?[0-9a-f]+)*)|0b(?:[10]+(?:'?[10]+)*)|\d+(?:'?\d+)*)(?:ull|ll|ul|l|u)?" input.txt`

PS: If you just want to extract the values a Perl script could come handy:

```
use strict;
my $file = '/some/where/input.txt';
my $regex = qr/(?:0x(?:[0-9a-f]+(?:'?[0-9a-f]+)*)|0b(?:[10]+(?:'?[10]+)*)|\d+(?:'?\d+)*)(?:ull|ll|ul|l|u)?/ip;
open my $input, '<', $file or die "can't open $file: $!";
while (<$input>) {
    chomp;
    while ($_ =~ /($regex)/g) {
      print "${^MATCH}\n";
    }
}
close $input or die "can't close $file: $!";
```